# Is a sonic screwdriver possible?

Tags: doctor-who, science, physics, engineering

Keeping it simple, is it possible to use sonic waves to apply rotary force to an object? And, if so, would it be possible to provide enough power to it via conventional battery tech?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about whether science fiction technology is possible in the real world are off-topic here.

Comment: Apologies. I'll post elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... yes.  And also, no.

Engineers have actually attempted this, with a degree of success.

There's an article here: http://www.themarysue.com/real-sonic-screwdriver/

**TL;DR**

Hypothetically, it is possible. In practise it can be achieved with large bulky equipment operating on a lightweight object which is responsive to the sonic waves.

It's a long way off being able to open doors and program computers, but there is hope.

Comment: Thanks for helping. However, it’s best not to post answers to questions that are off-topic, and such answers can also get in the way of eventual deletion. If you have relevant information, it’s probably fine to leave it in a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The article gives hope!

Comment: @Adamant - explain please how the answer was off-topic.  The question was whether a sonic screwdriver is possible. I answered that directly.

Also, I can't comment on the original post - not enough reputation.

Comment: No problem - sorry about that. Your *answer* is not off-topic: it addressed the question quite well. Rather, the *question* was off-topic, since it was about whether science fiction technology could be replicated in the real world. I was saying that it’s best not to write answers to off-topic questions.

Comment: @Adamant: _"If you have relevant information, it’s probably fine to leave it in a comment"_ Well, no; if the question is off-topic then it shouldn't be encouraged by being answered, as you said... but leaving the answer in comment _still does that_ but also does it in the wrong place. Which is double bad!

Comment: Thanks Adamant - I will remember that.  Agree - this question should really be in the Physics section. :-)